# How can I render an image over of my map?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to render a button on my map that looks like an image. However, the image does not display.

```
    <MapView.Callout>
          <View style={styles.callout}>
           <Image
              // style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
              source={{ uri: "../assets/sendSonar.png" }}
            >
          </Image>
          </View>
        </MapView.Callout>
```

If I use this to display a button, it works just fine.

```
        <MapView.Callout>
          <View style={styles.callout}>
            <Button title="Send Sonar" onPress={this.sendLocation} />
          </View>
        </MapView.Callout>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try to wrap your image inside ```TouchableOpacity``` and give height and width style to image.

Comment: I tried this but I still cannot see the image

Answer (score 0):

https://unbug.gitbooks.io/react-native-training/content/32_absolute_&_relative.html

You can use 'absolute' option for position